# Anri's whereabouts after the conversation at the bridge and killing Horace

Tags: dark-souls-3

I know this question has been asked a lot, and that's why it's so hard for me to pinpoint what is going on, as I believe my specific scenario is nowhere to be found. I followed each and every step in the [IGN Dark Souls 3 Guide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/dark-souls-3/Anri_of_Astora):

> **Usurpation of Fire**
>
> Step 5 - Inside the Catacombs of Carthus, you will find Anri in a
> hallway just before the first rolling skeleton ball. Speak with her
> several times.
>
> Step 6 - Head through the Catacombs of Carthus until you reach a wood
> bridge. If you see Anri, you can speak with her, but we suggest just
> ignoring her for now. Instead, cross the bridge, then attack it. The
> bridge will break, and you can climb down. Follow this path until you
> reach the Smouldering Lake.
>
> Step 7 - Once at the lake, turn right and follow the wall until you
> see a small tunnel. Walk through to the end and you'll find Horace the
> Hushed, but he has gone mad and attacks you. Kill him.
>
> Step 8 - Go back to the bridge you broke earlier. Before crossing it
> like you did before, look for a small side path. It will lead to Anri.
> Tell him/her about Horace.
>
> Step 9 - Head to Irithyll. Once you find the Church of Yorshka, you
> will find Anri inside. Speak to him/her until they have nothing left
> to say.

I was never able to meet up with Anri at the Church of Yorksha. Now here is what I did:

1. Followed Step 5
2. At Step 6, I spoke with Anri and took the option "say nothing".
3. Follow Step 9 to kill High Lord Wolnir.
4. Eventually, I went back to go down and kill Horace in the Smouldering Lake of Step 6 and Step 7.
5. When I go to Step 8, Anri is not available anymore; I can only find a glowing stone on the ground.

Anyone might happen to know if it's still possible to continue in this scenario, and if so, where could I find Anri?

Comment: I don't think step 8 is actually required, you should be able to go to Ithyrill and Anri will just say they failed to find Horace.

Comment: I think she already gave me the ring at some point in the church, hence why I cannot find her there anymore. Then my question remains, did she go somewhere else?

Comment: If you already went to the Yorshka church, then I think they're available as a summon for pontiff otherwise you won't see them again.